# fragment inside fragment {Kotlin}

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

is there any possible way to put a fragment inside a fragment?

I tried to put a viewPager in a fragment and write the code on OnCreatedView but it gives me error!!!

I tried this one but the fragments goes for every fragment in the activity!

pageradapter.kt

```
class pagerAdapter(fm:FragmentManager):FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
     return when(position){
        0-> Fragment1()
        1-> Fragment2()
        else -> null
    }

}


override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 2
}
 fun rotatePosition(position: Int):Int{
    return (count -1)-position
}

class pagerAdapter(fm:FragmentManager):FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
     return when(position){
        0-> Fragment1()
        1-> Fragment2()
        else -> null
    }

}


override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 2
}
 fun rotatePosition(position: Int):Int{
    return (count -1)-position
}
```

pageradapter2.kt

```
class pagerAdapter2(fm: FragmentManager):FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
    return when(position){
        0-> BlankFragment()
        else->null
    }
}

/**
 * Return the number of views available.
 */
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 1
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val pagerAdapter2 = pagerAdapter2(supportFragmentManager)
    val pager1= findViewById<View>(R.id.pager2) as ViewPager
    pager1.adapter = pagerAdapter2

    val adapter = pagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    val pager = findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
    pager.adapter = adapter
    pager.setCurrentItem(adapter.rotatePosition(0), false)
}
```

P.S. The first Answer solved my problem.

Comment: The second `ViewPager` in xml doesn't have constraints set to it which might lead to the second fragment to not render. What is the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: There isn't supportFragmentManger in OnCreatedView so it gives me the red color whenever I wrote it in the fragment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are adding fragment for an activity you use either `fragmentManager` or `supportFragmentManager`.

If you are adding fragment for a fragment - you should use `childFragmentManager`, accessing `fragmentManager` from fragment will lead to using the same one that activity does.